# How do I create an onClick drawLine function in swift?

Tags: swift, graphics

I need to create a function that will make a line connecting two buttons when they are pressed. However, the only way I can figure out how to create a line currently is with a predetermined start and endpoint.

```
func drawLineFrom(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0) /* SETTING LINE WIDTH: Set to the let and then the width next (let, width) */
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.purpleColor().CGColor) 
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, oldLocation.x, oldLocation.y)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, newLocation.x, newLocation.y)

    CGContextStrokePath(context)
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

When I call this function, in my class, by testing, I have figured out that the entire thing runs, and oldLocation and newLocation have the appropriate values to create a line. However, no line is created (or at least not visible). Is there a command I am neglecting to run, or is something else the problem?

Comment: Your code is (1) illegal and (2) useless. It's illegal because you begin an image context and you never end the context. It's useless because you never extract the actual image from the context and put that image into your interface.

Comment: in order to fix problem #1 would I just put "UIGraphicsEndImageContext()" at the end of the function?

Comment: Yes. - It might help you to read some of my online book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_graphics_contexts

Comment: Ok. I edited the first problem. Now I don't quite understand the second problem. I was under the impression the CGContextStrokePath(context) was the function that put the image into my interface. If I was so make this function return an image, how would you recommend I do that?

Comment: Hey, I wrote an explanation, I gave you a link to it. Reading it is up to you.